# facebook comment plugin not posting to facebook profile

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integerated facebook comment plugin in my site Pranknut (http://www.pranknut.com), but its not posting the comments to users' facebook profile. Although it shows comments in the site. Is it a bug in facebook ?. I have seen similar issue in other sites as well. 
I am using fb:comments for facebook comments.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, I left a comment on one of your links and it shows up in my activity feed. Is this still an issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be only with the FIRST comment being published.

If I, as admin, publish a comment, the first one doesn't even appear automatically - you need to refresh a page to see it - and it's also not published in my profile.

For the others, the comment appears on my site, but the first comment of every reader is not published to their profile.

Weird stuff :-(